# Questions regarding analog compensator

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, control, control-system

Consider the following analog compensator for a DC-DC converter.

[image]

Vo is the DC-DC converter.
FB is the feedback voltage.
Vref is the reference voltage.

It is expected that $$ FB = V_o\frac{R_4}{R_4 + R_1}  \quad\quad   (1)$$

However, for (1) to be held, it is necessary that R1 current is the same as R4 current. That means  the impedance looking into C1/C3/R2 has to be significantly larger than the resistance of R4.

Now suppose for a particular design, in order for the control loop to be stable, the values of C1/C3/R2 do not result in an impedance significantly larger than that of R1. In this case, (1) does not hold. Then under this condition, how can I establish a relation between Vo and FB? Is it necessary to take the values of C1, C3 and R2 into account when establish the relation between Vo and FB?

Source of the diagram: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva662/slva662.pdf?ts=1653989847679&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Are you looking for a simple DC relation or a full transfer function? Zf tends toward an open circuit at low frequencies, so an attempt to compare the impedance of R1 and Zf must be done with respect to some frequency of interest.

Comment: @nanofarad is it possible to have a simple DC relation in this case?

Comment: In this case, yes, R4/(R1+R4) * [open loop gain of the amp]. The Zf feedback network has no effect and the full feedback would be via the power stage controlled by Ve which ultimately drives Vo. The compensation network would reduce gain only at higher frequencies.

Comment: @nanofarad So if I want to establish a feedback and control loop at high frequency, it is necessary to consider all the passive elements, R1, R2, R4, C1 and C3? In real practice, is it common for a feedback equation to include the elements in the compensation network instead of just including the elements in the feedback network?

Comment: The compensation network is used to compensate for poor stability/insufficient phase margin in your overall control loop. If your feedback network is already fast and stable enough, you don't need it - I can't speak to what's typical since my background is RF, not DC-DC converters.

Comment: @nanofarad In case I need to use a compensator, can I consider a high frequency solution which include all the passive elements R1, R2, R4, C1 and C3 instead of just base on equation (1)?

Answer (score 1):

As shown, this integrates DC error to null average for steady state. Yet Type II compensation with voltage FB only has poor step response since there is latency in the error voltage.  Thus the metrics for gain and phase margin are poor.

Type III compensation includes a partial derivative or known as a lead/lag compensator to improve the phase margin hopefully to a target of 60 deg. Thus your Type II has integral and intermediate f proportional gain, but no derivative gain, performed only in type III.

The alternative is to use the derivative of voltage ripple into to a large C load which is current sensing and use proportional NFG gain for current sensing vs source impedance.

- *feedback network?* it depends on whether it is integrated or discrete.
- many are integrated with external options. for best results multiple feedback is used so that each is proportional to 2 different parameters like V, I for dI/dt step load is better on step responses, than just using Kd on V feedback alone which amplifies noise and may have excess stored energy with step to no load.

Comment: Even if Type III compensator is used, it is still not guaranteed that equation (1) as stated in the question is held, right?

Comment: @Underdog wrong (1) is true for all or no compensation types since Aol is high enough to eliminate input error as long as it is stable.

Comment: In real application, is it common for a feedback equation to include the elements in the compensation network instead of just including the elements in the feedback network?

Comment: either way, the result is the same and depends on how it is integrated or discrete. many are integrated with external options